# angularjs protractor Element is not clickable at point other element receive click with chrome

Tags: angularjs, protractor

Hi I am using simple angularjs application n facing issue with Protractor in chrome ,below is my sample code

```
HTML:

<div>
<div>
<ul......
<li.........../li>
<li............./li>
<li  id="projects123" role="temp" ng-click="mp.temp('temp')" ng-class="mp.temp">                                
    <span class="abc">Menu2 <span>{{mp.Length}}</span></span>                               
</li>
<...../ul>
</div></div>


Code For Protractor
conf.js

exports.config = {
  framework: 'jasmine',
  allScriptsTimeout: 120000,
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  specs: ['spec.js'],
  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome'
  },
  onPrepare: function() {
    browser.manage().window().setSize(1400, 800);
  },

  jasmineNodeOpts:{
      shadowColors:true,
      defaultTimeoutInterval:30000
  }
}

spec.js

"use strict";
describe('Project Home Page', function() {    
   it('Url Check', function() {   

    browser.get('http://localhost:80/app/index.html#/my-projects');     
    expect( browser.getCurrentUrl()).toEqual("http://localhost:80/app/index.html#/my-projects");      
  });  
  it('Open Project Details Page', function() {
      browser.sleep(5000);     
      element(by.id('projects123')).click();            
      browser.pause();     
  });
});
```

Whenever I am running this script with chrome , It says Element is not clickable at point (332, 88). Other element would receive the click: 
When I am running the same script with firefox I can see menu is clicked but with some other error. But it is clicking.
Please help.

Comment: Check if another pop-up is present or not. Like cookies notification etc

Answer (score 0):

Another element is covering the element you're trying to click. This is a [known bug](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/2313) in Protractor since it cannot tell when an element is being covered. Usually, you can get rid of pop-ups by clicking an arbitrary element on the page, for instance clicking a blank div will rid the screen of a visible hover element.